# Laravel undefined variable issue

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get data from database and print it using foreach loop but I have undefined variable error.

In my web.php I have

```
Route::get('/ShowProducts' , 'ProductController@ShowProducts');
```

This is my code in controller

```php
function ShowProducts(){
    $show = ProductModel::where('ID')->get();

    $show->Product_Name;
    $show->Count;
    $show->Price;

    return view('profile');
}
```

Comment: ` $show = ProductModel::where('ID')->get();`. where id what? You need to give a value to compare in your where clause

Comment: I suspect you aren't passing the data to your view, can you post the code of your view as well please?

Comment: please post your full error message and which file and line number you are getting this error?

Comment: your code doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: can you show you blade file code?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have `$id` argument on your function, if you want to list all products, use this:

```php
function ShowProducts() {
   $products = ProductModel::all();
   return view('profile', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

and on your blade:

```php
@foreach($products as $prod)
    <h3 class="product-title">
        <a href="product.html">{{$prod->Product_Name}}</a>
    </h3>
@endforeach
```

If you want to show a single product, add a new route with `{id}`:

```
Route::get('/ShowProducts/{id}' , 'ProductController@ShowProduct');
```

and on your controller:

```php
function ShowProduct($id) {
   $product = ProductModel::findOrFail($id);
   return view('profile', ['product' => $product]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello this is normal because you do not pass the variable to your view.

```
 function ShowProducts(){
   $show = ProductModel::where('ID')->get();
   return view('profile', compact('show'));
}
```

Now just use $show in your blade.

Comment: What does compact function do?

Comment: Sorry but I have the same error. In my blade I have  @foreach($show as $prod) 3 class="product-title"><a href="product.html">{{$prod->Product_Name}}</a></h3>                                        @endforeach

Comment: class ProductModel extends Model
{
    public $table = 'products';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function photos(){
        
        return $this->hasMany(
            'App\PhotoModel', 'Product_id' , 'ID'
        );

    }
    public function saller(){
        
        return $this->belongsTo(
            'App\UserModel' , 'user_ID' , 'ID' 
        );
        // belongsTo one to many kapy

    }
}

Comment: add this `protected $fillable = ['Product_Name'];` add all your field (field DB) on this array

Answer (score 1):

first of all, where is the actual `ID` you are looking for?

Secondly, what is `$show->Product_Name;` for?

Thirdly, go to laracasts.com and follow some tutorials. The function you are looking for is:

```
Route::get('/ShowProducts/{id}' , 'ProductController@ShowProducts');

function ShowProducts($id){
    $show = ProductModel::find($id);
    return view('profile', compact('show'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few strange things in this code:

```
$show = ProductModel::where('ID')->get();
```

This query does not compare any value. You need a proper where clause like:

```
ProductModel::where('ID','=',$id)->get(); //ID is the AI column in your database, make sure you used capital letters for that.
```

Next is your variable assignment. In laravel `get` is used to return a collection of records. In your case you need something like `first()` since you filter on id.

```
 ProductModel::where('ID','=',$id)->first();
```

Then you will be able to assign values like you tried, but in your code :

```
$show->Product_Name;
$show->Count;
$show->Price;
```

Those fields are currently `undefined`, cause there is a nested array there with key [0], because you return only 1 record of course. That's how `get()` works. So instead as i mentioned above use `first()` for this task.

Answer (score 1):

make your code as below.

**controller code**.

```
function ShowProducts(){
    $products = ProductModel::all();
    return view('profile', compact('products'));
}
```

**profile.blade.php** file.

```
@if(!empty($products))
@foreach($products as $product)
 {{ $product->Product_Name }}
@endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: My table is not empty but it does not print the name of product

Comment: can you `print_r($products)` in blade file to see what is actually in products variable.?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass variable into view. you didn't do it, that's why you got `undefined variable` error.

There are many methods to pass variables into view.

**`Using array directly in view method`**

```
return view('welcome', ['variable_name' => $variable_value]);
```

**`Using with method`**

```
return view('welcome')->with('variable_name', $variable_value);
```

**`Using with method shortcut`**

```
return view('welcome')->withVar($variable_value);
// laravel parses 'withVariable' method name then extracts variable name and you will get variable called 'var' in your blade file
```

**`Using php's compact function`**

```
// It is more clear and readable to use compact if you are not doing conditionals and etc
$var1 = 'val1';
$var2 = 'val2';
return view('welcome', compact('var1', 'var2'));
// Compact methods gets variable name by string and retuns associative array with 'name' => 'value' signature
```

> I usually use firs and last methods

Hope this helps you